# Getting a JSON array/object inside a json object

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get JSON Array/Object named **stats** inside my main JSON object called **docs** in my JSONAdapter class, and seem like everything I was trying to do wasn't working.

Let's say I need to get the following values:

[JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8r8P.png)

I already using the data from the **docs** JSON Object in my JSONAdapter class like this:

```
String summonerName = jsonObject.optString("summonerName");
```

which is:
**docs->summonerName**.

how do I get **docs->stats->numWins**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("stats").optString("numWins");
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonObject.optJSONObject("stats")` to get the `stats` object. To get the `numWins` or any other value you can chain it like this

```
String numWins = jsonObject.optJSONObject("stats").optString("numWins");
```

For a `JSONObject`, `opt` will return `null` if the key doesn't exist, or the datatype for that key is incorrect. You can use this to prevent crashing, doing something like this

```
String numWins = null;
JSONObject stats = jsonObject.optJSONObject("stats");
if(stats != null)
   numWins = stats.optString("numWins");
```

Keep in mind that `numWins` could still be `null,` so check that before doing anything with it.

Comment: I get a java.lang.NullPointerException